# ionic\angular 2: string does not updated after settimeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to update a string (of a class\tag) with settimeout (or any other callback), with no success, It's working perfectly with a button (when the user is clicking the button to update), but it doesn't work with JS settimeout.
can you tell me what am I missing here?

**Here is a sample of the code I have:**

```
export class Page1 {
  constructor() {
this.greet = "Hi, ";
setTimeout(function(){
  this.greet = "Hello, ";
  alert("Done");
 }, 3000);
  }
}
```

as you can see in this simple code, I can see the alert "Done" after 3 seconds, but the greeting is not updated, should I refresh it somehow?

Thanks for helping!

Eran.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your way `this` inside setTimeout callback isn't instance of `Page1` class. You need to use arrow function to retain context:

```
setTimeout(() => { // <=== 
  this.greet = "Hello, ";
  alert("Done");
}, 3000);
```

See this link for more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this